# Elasticsearch MLT query with Elastica for PHP

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, elastica

Wondering if this from the [Elasticsearch official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html):

```
{
    "more_like_this" : {
        "fields" : ["name.first", "tweet"],
        "like" : [
        {
            "_index" : "marvel",
            "_type" : "quotes",
            "doc" : {
                "name": {
                    "first": "Ben",
                    "last": "Grimm"
                },
                "tweet": "You got no idea what I'd... what I'd give to be invisible."
              }
        },
        ],
        "min_term_freq" : 1,
        "max_query_terms" : 1
    }
}
```

is yet implemented within the latest release of [Elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica)?
The bit I am struggling with is the "doc" section of the "like".

My code is as follow:

```
$moreLikeThis = (new Query\MoreLikeThis())
    ->setFields([
        'name.first',
        'tweet'
    ])
    ->setLike((new Document())
        ->setIndex('myIndexName')
        ->setType('myTypeName')
        ->setData([
            'tweet'      => 'Foo',
            'name' => [
                'first' => 'Bar',
                'last' => 'Test'
            ]
        ])
    )
    ->setMinTermFrequency(1)
    ->setMinDocFrequency(1);
```

But it looks like the query is not generated properly. Here is what I get when I var_dump() Request::toString():

> string(398)
>   "{"path":"myIndexName/myTypeName/_search","method":"GET","data":{"query":{"more_like_this":{"fields":["name.first","tweet"],"like":{"_id":"","_type":"myTypeName","_index":"myIndexName"},"min_term_freq":1,"min_doc_freq":1}}},"query":{"search_type":"count"},"connection":{"config":[],"host":"localhost","port":9200,"enabled":true}}"

The "doc" section if definitely missing? Am I not using it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is wondering, the feature was actually not fully implemented within Elastica.

[It's fixed now](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/pull/1051).